# Click-through WPF window + content while still catching events

Tags: wpf

Basically what I'm trying to do is have a window with controls that responds to the mouse and keyboard, but does not take focus. I've been looking into hooking into the window events to catch them or using the preview events and not handling them, but whatever I do, the window either fires the mouse and keyboard events and takes focus or does not do anything at all.

Is it possible to hook to the mouse/keyboard events for a window manually while still passing the events to any window (other applications too) behind it?

**Edit:**

I've tried the code below to make the window click-through, but this causes mouse and keyboard events not to be fired at all.

```
    public const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020; public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get this window's handle         
        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        // Change the extended window style to include WS_EX_TRANSPARENT         
        int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);

        var hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;

        if (hwndSource != null)
            hwndSource.CompositionTarget.RenderMode = RenderMode.Default;

        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, 
 Are the controls you mention user controls you have written yourself ?

Comment: Hi, 
Are the controls you mention user controls you have written yourself ?
You can trap events from Bubbling Events (the control back to the Window) or Tunneling Event (from the Window down to the control.  Up to you if you wish to handle them at what ever level.  The control would not require a focus.  This is withing a single application of course.  Passing say a mouse or keyboard event to another application would depend on whether it is 'listening' for such.  Hope that helps a bit.  Also some code that you have tried would be beneficial.

Comment: The controls are the default controls from WPF. I've already tried trapping the events, but like you said it only works within a single application.

I have tried making the window click-through successfully using the code I added to the main post, but this also causes events such as the mousedown and mousepreview events not to fire.

Comment: About whether the application is 'listening': The application that's behind the WPF window should use it's default behaviour for the events that are passed to it. If for example the desktop is behind the WPF window, a click on the WPF window would fire an action in the WPF application as well as it could possibly select an icon on the desktop.